# How can I print out the letters that are contained in an ArrayList, in one line?

Tags: c#

This program is supposed to print out "This website is for losers LOL!" but without any vowels.

"Ths wbst s fr lsrs LL!"

My problem is that so far I have only figured out how to print out one letter per line, not the whole sentence in one line.

Also, ideally, I should be able to remove the vowels from my ArrayList and then print out the ArrayList in one line without any vowels

```
string str = "This website is for losers LOL!";
ArrayList arrayOfLetters = new ArrayList();
string letter = "";
string sentence = "";

foreach (char c in str)
{
    arrayOfLetters.Add(c);
}

for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    letter = arrayOfLetters[i] + "";

    if( letter.Contains("a") || letter.Contains("e") || letter.Contains("i") || letter.Contains("o") || letter.Contains("u")) 
    {
    } 
    else 
    { 
        print (letter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public static string RemoveVowels(this string text) {
     var vowels = "aeiou";
     return new string(text.Where(c => !vowels.Contains(c)).ToArray());
}
```

Usage:

```
var text = "StackOverflow is not for losers!";
var noVowels = text.RemoveVowels();
```

Comment: `y` is not a vowel, at least not in normal English.

Comment: Regarding 'y' - I'd have doubts whenever I see "vowel" when someone referes to "letters". When seeing character `y` it's quite hard to tell what sound will it actually produce, and this defines whever will it generate a vowel or consonant. That's my opinion, I'm english-as-second-language guy, so my view point might be skewed. However, please check for example: [Is the letter Y a vowel or a consonant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/is-the-letter-y-a-vowel-or-a-consonant)

Answer (score 0):

```
str.Where(l => l != 'a' && l != 'e' && l != 'i' && l != 'o' && l != 'u')
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(Console.Write);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have visual studio available  at the moment, but I would like for you to check this out. Should be what you are looking for 
[String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx)